# Bash compose array with the input of other arrays, respecting a specific loop order

Tags: bash, shell-script, array

I am trying to generate a new array, with the combination of other arrays, respecting a specific sequence. In pure Bash. Example:

```
numbers=(0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8);

colors=(red blue green);

loop_sequence=(numbers numbers colors numbers colors colors)
```

Example output:

```
0 1 red 2 blue green 3 4 red 5 blue green 6 7 red 8 blue green 0 1 red 2 blue green...
```

But I find very difficult to make the internal loops of iterations. Any help is very welcome.

Comment: I wouldn't have bothered answering if I had seen [the same question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/33857548/7552) on stackoverflow. Don't post the same question on multiple sites.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dynamic variable names are tricky in bash, but do-able with variable indirection.

```
numbers=(0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8)
colors=(red blue green)
loop_sequence=(numbers numbers colors numbers colors colors)

# keep track of where you are in each array
declare -A idx=([numbers]=0 [colors]=0)

for varname in "${loop_sequence[@]}"; do 
    tmp="${varname}[${idx[$varname]}]"   # construct the array reference
    echo "$varname => ${!tmp}"           # variable indirection gets the value
    (( idx[$varname]++ ))
done
```

outputs

```
numbers => 0
numbers => 1
colors => red
numbers => 2
colors => blue
colors => green
```

To indefinitely repeat the loop_sequence, you can:

```
declare -A idx=([numbers]=0 [colors]=0)
# store the array sizes for convenience
declare -A size=([numbers]=${#numbers[@]} [colors]=${#colors[@]})
while true; do 
    for varname in "${loop_sequence[@]}"; do 
        tmp="${varname}[${idx[$varname]}]"
        echo "$varname => ${!tmp}"
        # loop the array index
        (( idx[$varname] = (idx[$varname]+1) % size[$varname] ))
    done
done | less
```

Comment: that's a pretty neat trick.

Comment: what if the loop sequence should be the lengh to cover the full iteration of the longest array, while the shorter array iteration loop to prevent blank strings outputs and the break of the sequence?

Comment: then change `while true` to ... something else.

Comment: Well Thank you, and sorry for double askin in stackoverflow, my first day using the sites. Your coding is very good.

Comment: Can I use this code for, 3, 4 or more arrays combinations, named in the 'loop_sequence' array? Then I would just need to add then to the declare -A line too?

Comment: How do I output this to a new array?   Only the values, and not the echo line with "array name ==>"

Comment: if `a` is an array, `a+=("some value")` appends to the array.

Answer (score 0):

```
x=$(( (l=${#loop_sequence[@]}) * (n=${#numbers[@]}) * (c=${#colors[@]})))
_n= _c= _l=
set --    
math(){ return "$(($1-=-($1<${1#?})|$1-1))"; }
while   [ "$((x-=1))" -ge 0 ]
do      math _l
        case "${loop_sequence[$?-1]}" in
        n*)  math _n
             set -- "$@" "${numbers[$?-1]}";;
        *)   math _c
             set -- "$@" "${colors[$?-1]}";;
        esac
done;   printf %s\\n  "$@"
```

---

```
0
1
red
2
blue
green
3
4
red
5
blue
green
6
7
red
8
blue
green
0
1
red
2
blue
green
3
4
red
5
blue
green
6
7
red
8
blue
green
0
1
red
2
blue
green
3
4
red
5
blue
green
6
7
red
8
blue
green
0
1
red
2
blue
green
3
4
red
5
blue
green
6
7
red
8
blue
green
0
1
red
2
blue
green
3
4
red
5
blue
green
6
7
red
8
blue
green
0
1
red
2
blue
green
3
4
red
5
blue
green
6
7
red
8
blue
green
0
1
red
2
blue
green
3
4
red
5
blue
green
6
7
red
8
blue
green
0
1
red
2
blue
green
3
4
red
5
blue
green
6
7
red
8
blue
green
0
1
red
2
blue
green
3
4
red
5
blue
green
6
7
red
8
blue
green
```